# How to add a subscript symbol in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects, subscript, sup

I want to add this ® subscript symbol after *[SAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP)*. How can I do it?

```
{
    number: '02',
    title: 'Multiple Automation Agents ',
    descriptionTwo: [
        'Achieve 100% savings on infra scaling & Additional SOX Cost',
        'Eliminate GUI based automation for SAP with SAP NetWeaver ABAP Automation Studio ',
        'Realize speed and reliability with Low-code RPA Agent employing libraries as opposed to traditional coding',
        'Conquer challenges of automation in API based systems like ServiceNow, Salesforce with API Agent',
    ],
},
```

The same this in HTML: `SAP<sup>®</sup>`

Comment: FYI `<sup></sup>` is _superscript_ not subscript which is `<sub></sub>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: {
      number: '02',
      title: 'Multiple Automation Agents ',
      descriptionTwo: [
        'Achieve 100% savings on infra scaling & Additional SOX Cost',
        'Eliminate GUI based automation for SAP<sup>®</sup> with SAP<sup>®</sup> NetWeaver ABAP Automation Studio ',
        'Realize speed and reliability with Low-code RPA Agent employing libraries as opposed to traditional coding',
        'Conquer challenges of automation in API based systems like ServiceNow, Salesforce with API Agent',
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="(item, index) in message.descriptionTwo" :key="index">
    <li v-html="item"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```